# Argumento ao inicializar o Weka

Tags: java, compilação, weka

Na [página de download do Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html) há a recomendação de inicializar o arquivo .jar do Weka com o seguinte argumento `-Xmx1000M`. Porém não entendi o que o argumento irá alterar na hora que o Weka é executado. Sendo que a inicialização funciona mesmo sem o argumento, qual a diferença?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este parâmetro define o tamanho máximo do **Heap** disponível para o Weka usar.

Pode ler o que é o Heap [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-o-stack-e-heap).